# Computing $x \pmod 5$ if we only know $x \pmod 7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let's say we have a number $n$ of which I know its value $x$ modulo $k$, then how can I calculate its value modulo $l$?

For example; $n=271, k=7$, and $l=8$, so $x=271 \textrm{ mod } 7=5$. How can I calculate what $n \textrm{ mod } 8$ is **only given** that $x=5$ and that $x$ was calculated modulo $7$? (So I do not know the original value $n$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k$ and $l$ are relatively prime, then knowing $n$ modulo $k$ gives *absolutely no information* about its value modulo $l$. All values from $0$ through $l-1$ are possible. This is due to the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) and various other theorems..

Now, if $l$ divides $k$ then we could give an answer. For example, if $n$ is $5$ modulo $8$ then it is $1$ modulo $4$. The idea should be clear to you on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't. In fact, if $m_1$ is coprime to $m_2$, then there are solutions to the pair of modular congruences
$$ \begin{align}
x \equiv a_1 \pmod {m_1} \\
x \equiv a_2 \pmod {m_2}
\end{align}$$
for any $a_1, a_2$. In other words, you cannot figure out what $a_2$ is if you only know $a_1, m_1$, and $m_2$. This is called the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

In the event that $m_2$ divides $m_1$, then you can find $a_2$ given $a_1$. But that is the only case.